# String is not outputting newline to View table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to combine multiple error messages in my check, but sometimes it finds that the site is missing and the errors string is not blank. When this happens, it will display both errors, but it will not output it on a new line.

Here is an example...

[image]

According to the code it should be saying

> Unsupported date format of 1/06/19.
>
> Site is missing

Below is my check

```
    private void FileCheck(string[] strArray, out string INum, out string IDate, out string site, out string errors)
    {
        INum = strArray[1];
        IDate = strArray[2];
        errors = "";
        site = strArray[10];
        string[] errorformats = {$"Unsupported date format of {IDate}.", "Site is missing"};
        string[] format = {"MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"};
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(IDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
            errors = errorformats[0];
        if (site == "" && errors != "")
            errors = $"{errorformats[0]}{Environment.NewLine}{errorformats[1]}";
        else if (site == "" && errors == "")
            errors = errorformats[1];
    }
```

I call it using the below code

```
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(newFullPath))
                {
                    while ((strbuild = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var strArray = strbuild.Split('|');
                        string INum = string.Empty,
                            IDate = string.Empty,
                            site = string.Empty,
                            errors = string.Empty;

                        if (strArray[0] == "1")
                        {
                            FileCheck(strArray, out INum, out IDate, out site, out errors);
```

Here is the code for my table:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <!--Table Head-->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row</th>
                <th>Invoice #</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <!--Table Body-->
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr class="table-info">
                    <th scope="row">@i</th>
                    <td>@Model[i].InvoiceNumber </td>
                    <td>@Model[i].Errors </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: When you say `if (A) {...} else if (B) {...}` etc, it will only process the block after the *first* true statement. That's what the `else` means, so if A is true, it will never evaluate B. Remove the `else` and your code will probably work, though there are clearer ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks @iakobski for bringing that to my attention. I've updated my question with the new code and result. The question remains the same though.

Comment: So what does the HTML look like now?

Comment: I updated the picture as well when I updated the controller code.

Comment: Yes, I can see the picture, what does the HTML look like?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. HTML at the time remained unchanged from original question. My question is now answered Using Ashvani's answer in combination with your conditional change, and Erics concat change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar problem once and this worked. Just give it a try.

```
<td>@Html.Raw(Model[i].Errors) </td>
```

Comment: This works in combination with Eric's answer of using `errors = $"{errorformats[0]}<br>{errorformats[1]}";` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating with `Environment.NewLine`, concat with `<br>`.

```
errors = $"{errorformats[0]}<br>{errorformats[1]}";
```

Browsers usually don't show the `\r` and `\n` characters, leaving a blank space or breaking altogether.

Comment: This is not the right answer. The statement `else if (site == "" && errors != "")` can never evaluate to true, `errors` is always empty at that point.

Comment: That is also true, @iakobski. I failed to fully evaluate the code and let that pass.
Still, the consideration about `Environment.NewLine` remains.

Comment: @iakobski You are correct about the conditionals. I've updated my code. That was my fault. Eric, I do not believe <br> will do the trick though due to the string being parsed as a literal in my table. It ends up outputting `Unsupported date format of 12/06/19.<br>Site is missing` all on one line.